# regex for specific delimiter string in Hive serde

Tags: regex, hadoop, hive, hive-serde

I use serde to read data with specific format with delimiter |

One line of my data may looks like: **key1=value2|key2=value2|key3="va , lues"**, and I create the hive table as below:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE(
field1 STRING,
field2 STRING,
field3 STRING
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.RegexSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  "input.regex" = "([^\\|]*)\\|([^\\|]*)\\|([^\\|]*)",
  "output.format.string" = "%1$s %2$s %3$s"
)
STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```

I need to extract all values, ignore all quotas if they exist.
Result looks like a

```
 value2  value2 va , lues
```

How can I change my current regexp for extractig values ?

Comment: What is your current output result for the given input?

Comment: key1=value2 key2=value2 key3="va , lues"

Comment: So just change this: `"input.regex" = "[^\\|=]*=\"?([^\\|]*)\"?\\|[^\\|=]*=\"?([^\\|]*)\"?\\|[^\\|=]*=\"?([^\\|]*)\"?",`

Comment: The use-case seems strange. How come you don't need the keys?

Comment: @horcrux - `|` might be contained within a quoted value

Answer (score 0):

I can currently offer 2 options, none of them is perfect.
BTW, `"output.format.string"` is obsolete and has no effect.

#### 1

```
create external table mytable
(
    q1          string    
   ,field1      string
   ,q2          string
   ,field2      string
   ,q3          string
   ,field3      string
)
row format serde 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.RegexSerDe'
with serdeproperties ('input.regex' = '.*?=(?<q1>"?)(.*?)(?:\\k<q1>)\\|.*?=(?<q2>"?)(.*?)(?:\\k<q2>)\\|.*?=(?<q3>"?)(.*?)(?:\\k<q3>)')
stored as textfile
;
```

---

```
select * from mytable
;
```

---

```
+----+--------+----+--------+----+-----------+
| q1 | field1 | q2 | field2 | q3 |  field3   |
+----+--------+----+--------+----+-----------+
|    | value2 |    | value2 | "  | va , lues |
+----+--------+----+--------+----+-----------+
```

#### 2

```
create external table mytable
(
    field1 string
   ,field2 string
   ,field3 string
)
row format serde 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.RegexSerDe'
with serdeproperties ('input.regex' = '.*?=(".*?"|.*?)\\|.*?=(".*?"|.*?)\\|.*?=(".*?"|.*?)')
stored as textfile
;
```

---

```
select * from mytable
;
```

---

```
+--------+--------+-------------+
| field1 | field2 |   field3    |
+--------+--------+-------------+
| value2 | value2 | "va , lues" |
+--------+--------+-------------+
```